# Installing python-tesseract on Ubuntu 15.x

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am having problems installing `python-tesseract` on Ubuntu systems.
 I've tried with several versions of Ubuntu systems of 32 bits from 14.04 onwards and I got nothing. I downloaded `python-tesseract_0.9-0.5ubuntu2_i386.deb` and tried to install it but dependency problems show up, and after installing the needed packages, these problems does not disappear.

How can I install python-tesseract on **Ubuntu 14.04** or **15.10**? Thanks

**Edit:** I am developing an optical character recognition application on python, and I need to access to the lot of functions that tesseract `TessBaseAPI` gives. I found several wrappers of tesseract for python, but `python-tesseract` (I have understood that is not the same that pytesseract) is the only one that allows access to all functions, and not only to a few. I downloaded a `python-tesseract.deb` file, but the problems described above arise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works installing gdebi-core first, and afterwards installing the .deb package with it, so that gdebi install dependencies for me. I used Ubuntu 14.04.

```
 sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
 sudo gdebi python-tesseract_0.9-0.5ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

Comment: i have ubuntu 16.04 and i want to install pytesseract version 0.1.x, suggest me how can i install it?

Answer (score 0):

tesseract has been available in the "universe" repository since at least 2012, I suggest you install the `tesseract-ocr` package with apt-get. Test to make sure the tesseract command is working.

Then if the deb isn't working for you, do a pip install. Be sure to carefully follow the instructions in [the pypi package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract)

Comment: Yes, I installed tesseract-ocr correctly, but I want to access to it from python, using the wrapper python-tesseract, which is the hard to install. Thanks.